# Faster Than 1ms But Slower Than a Loop

Tags: performance, loops, timer

I need to execute some lines of code multiple times (say, 300 times) in rapid succession, each time incrementing some variable and then using it do to a task (let's assume it's a task that requires negligible time to complete).

I tried doing it with a timer set to 1 ms, but it runs too slowly. I then tried doing it with a `While` loop, but that was much too fast. I could use `Threading.Sleep` but I really hate using that, not to mention it can only sleep as short as 1 ms anyways. I also thought of using `Environment.TickCount` but I believe that counts in milliseconds as well.

While this program isn't important to me, it got me wondering if such a thing was possible. A loop that could run with "faster than 1 ms intervals," but slower than "as fast as the program can execute it."

Comment: Having trouble finding a suitable way to do this is not accidental.  There is no way the OS can provide you a guarantee that this code will behave predictably.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind is calculating the waiting for every iteration yourself with a high precision clock like javas System.nanoTime().

Yet, the call itself is relatively costly and will not let you do nano second precision waiting. But for waiting shorter than 1ms and longer than e.g. 1ns this might help.